# Using VBA to Input/access a value in an element inside an iFrame which is nested inside Frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vba, frame

This Problem of mine already lasted for weeks I am currently in my internship and the unit I am with tasked me to automate the search in their system. I know already how getElements work somehow, This is what you can see in inspect elements:

```
<DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "=..../frameset.dtd>
<html xmlns=...>
<head>
<frameset style>
<Frame name = "Frame1" src = "Frame1.aspx">
<Frame name = "Frame2" src = "Frame2.aspx">
                     |
                     V
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ".....transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns=...>
   <head>
   <body>
   <form name = "form1" id ="form1">
   <div id="appiDIVA">
      <iframe name = appiFrame class="aFrame" src="Router.aspx">
       <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-...Frameset.dtd">
       <html xmlns=...>
       <head>
       <frameset style = "">
        <frame name = "LeftPage" id = "LeftPage">
          <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-...something.dtd">
          <html xmlns=...>
          <head>
          <body class = "left frame">
           <form id="frmleftForm action = LeftFrame.aspx" method = "post">
           <div>
           <script type = "javascript">
           <script src = ".....">
                    .
                    .
                    .
           <div class = "searchbox">
            <select name = ctlSearch$.. id = ctlSearch_... onchange = javascript... >
            ***<a tabindex="2" class="find" id = searchbutton onclick = "return......." href = "javascript:_..........">***
            <div id ="ctlsearchupdate">
            <span id="ctlsearchtxtfind" style="...">
            ***<input name ="ctlsearch$findthis" tab index="1" id = ctlsearch_" accesskey="4" type="text" maxlength="25" autcomplete="off">***
```

The Elements that I need to access/change are the ones with the asterisks in the code. The problem is that those Elements that I need to put my input or click is inside a **NESTED/EMBEDDED FRAME**

I did multiple things such as checking the elements present through `Textbox1.text = IE.document.body.innerHTML` when I did that it only showed:

```
<frame name = "Frame1" src = "Frame1.aspx" frame border = "0" noresize="noresize">
<frame name = "Frame2" src = "Frame2.aspx" frame border = "0" noresize="noresize">
```

Then I researched about the code:

```
Textbox1.Text = IE.document.getElementsById("ContentFrame").contentDocument.DocumentElement.innerHTML
```

This then showed the elements till the `<iframe name = appiFrame class="aFrame" src="Router.aspx">` not showing its contents nor anything below it.

As shown in the codes above the Elements are within frame2 I am stuck for weeks already as to how to atleast input a value to the textbox.

Then I did this:

```
PrivateSub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
   Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium

   Set doc = IE.document.frames.frames(1).document.getElementsByName("appiFrame")(0)


   If(doc Is Nothing) Then
      MsgBox("Element Not Detected")
   Else
      MsgBox("Detected")
      TextBox1.Text = IE.document.body.innerHTML
      MsgBox(doc)
   End If
End Sub
```

What happens in here is that the **iFrame** is now detected by the message popping **[objectHTMLIFrameElement]** but the innerHTML still only displays the **two framesets**, I am stuck as how I could advance forward or dig the elements. Would appreciate if I could at least get a helping hand Thanks!